# How to use react-native-billing

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase

as per title, my app crashes as soon as i use the `purchase()` method

Tested on a clean react-native project: i literally just issued `react-native init testProj`, `npm install`, `npm install --save react-native-billing`, `react-native link react-native-billing`.
Then i proceeded to set `new InAppBillingBridgePackage(APP_KEY)` in my **MainApplication.java**

This is the only code i edited in **index.android.js**

```
export default class testProj extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
      const InAppBilling = require("react-native-billing")
      console.log(InAppBilling)

      InAppBilling.open()
          .then(() => InAppBilling.purchase('android.test.purchased'))
          .then((details) => {
              console.log("You purchased: ", details)
              return InAppBilling.close()
          })
          .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
          });
  }  
  render() {...}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "testProj",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.46.3",
    "react-native-billing": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "jest": {
   "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Once the app reaches this `componentDidMount`, a purchase dialog loads for a split second then crashes both my app and Play Store in the background. Running `adb logcat *:E` during the above shows this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(31592): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
E/AndroidRuntime(31592): Process: com.android.vending, PID: 31592
E/AndroidRuntime(31592): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime(31592):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
E/AndroidRuntime(31592):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
E/AndroidRuntime(31592):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
E/AndroidRuntime(31592):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
E/AndroidRuntime(31592):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/AndroidRuntime(31592):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(31592):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
E/AndroidRuntime(31592): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'long com.google.wireless.android.finsky.dfe.nano.an.b' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime(31592):    at com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.s.a(SourceFile:5)
E/AndroidRuntime(31592):    at com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.h.doInBackground(SourceFile:27)
E/AndroidRuntime(31592):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
E/AndroidRuntime(31592):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(31592):    ... 3 more
```

**Long story short: am I missing something obvious?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens when testing in-app billing with static responses. It looks like a problem with new versions of Google Play Store. We tested 3 versions of Play Store. 
7.4 works as expected, 7.8 and 8.0 crashes.

At the moment, we're looking for a solution too.